# FInd data in table with both cases of value of data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:

```
   A:         B:
  ID          NAME:
  STATE       STATE_ID
              card


A.ID  ||  A.STATE || B.NAME || B.STATE_ID || B.CARD
  1          FOO       Hans      1            44

  2          BAR       HANS      2            44
  1          FOO       JOHN      1            55
  1          FOO       HANS      1            22
```

What i need is to retrieve Name from table B , which has both states, Foo and Bar, in this case its Hans with card number 44.

In this case when cards are the same we know we are talking about same user ( B ).

What i tried to do:

```
Select name FROM B 
  INNER JOIN A 
    on (A.ID = B.STATE_ID )
```

this joins the table , and now i am trying to merge results. e.g find all B's with both states FOO and BAR.

However, the state can have more than 2 values , and user with for example state Foo and notFoo should not be found.

However i cannot think of correct solutions.

What is the best way to achieve this result?

All helps and explanations are highly appreciated

Comment: Why is it Hans with card number 44 and not Hans with card number 55 or 22?

Comment: typo, fixed the table , thanks

Comment: Are the names really in mixed case (sometimes Hans, sometimes HANS)? If so, why? Then, it seems the same name may be associated with different card numbers; so the grouping is by card number, or by (name, card) - and not by name alone?

Comment: You need to clarify one more thing. Suppose a name/card pair has several rows, and there is 'FOO' and 'BAR' but there is also another row where the STATE (or STATE_ID) is different from 'FOO' and 'BAR'. Do you need to include this name/card pair in the output (because it has both 'FOO' and 'BAR'), or do you exclude it (because it **also** has something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest method is:

```
SELECT name
FROM B INNER JOIN
     A 
     ON A.ID = B.STATE_ID
WHERE state IN ('foo', 'bar')
GROUP BY name, card
HAVING MIN(state) <> MAX(state);
```

Comment: It seems NAME is not unique (see Hans in the OP's example) and instead the PK (of some other table!) is either CARD alone or (NAME, CARD). So the GROUP BY should be by CARD or NAME, CARD. But other than that, this is indeed the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly you want a query like the following:

```
SELECT B.Name
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON b.STATE_ID = A.ID
GROUP BY B.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN STATE IN ('Foo', 'Bar') THEN STATE END) = 2 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE IN ('Foo', 'Bar') THEN STATE END) = COUNT(*)
```

The first predicate in the `HAVING` clause guarantees that only names having *both* `'Foo'` and `'Bar'` are returned. The second guarantees that only names having `'Foo'` and `'Bar'` and *nothing else* are returned.

Comment: The advantage of filtering by state or state_id (in a WHERE clause, as in Gordon's solution) is that fewer - or possibly far fewer - rows need to be read from disk in the first place. The optimizer may see what you are doing in the HAVING clause and rewrite the query so it doesn't read unnecessary rows - but it may miss it, too.

Comment: @mathguy Yes, but this would filter out any records related to non-Foo or non-Bar states. Hence, we wouldn't be able to check whether foo/bar are the *only* states the `Name` is related to.

Comment: You are right. This is not clear from the OP's question - I will ask him/her in a comment. Do they want to exclude a name/card if a state OTHER THAN 'FOO' and 'BAR' is present?